# how to check if an object exists in an array which is found in a global class in C#

Tags: c#, object, instance, exists

I am making a game which has a global (static) class called MedGameController. In my class I have two arrays of fifteen objects each which hold the logic for each players units. In the game the player's go to a form where they see their already created units and have buttons to create more units. I don't know how to check if current units exist though so I can't even create a single unit. How do I check if the instance of my unit class exists in the array? The array of units have to have a scope which incompasses two maybe three forms so that is why I created them in a global class. Here is the global class:

```
static class MedGameController      
{
    static int ply1pts;
    static int ply2pts;
    Squad[] ply1squads = new Squad[15];
    Squad[] ply2squads = new Squad[15];

    public static int SetPly1Pts
    {
        get { return ply1pts; }
        set { ply1pts = value; }
    }

    public static int SetPly2Pts
    {
        get { return ply2pts; }
        set { ply2pts = value; }
    }

    public static int SquadSetUp
    {
        get { return squadcreation; }
        set { squadcreation = value; }
    }
    public static void Player1Squads
    {
        This is where I think i'm supposed to check if they exist then if it doesn't then I create the instance of the squad class
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. What is Player1Squads supposed to do? Will it create 15 new Squads in the ply1squads array? Or create 1 Squad and add it to the array? Or what?

Comment: play1squads and ply2squads must be static if you wish to access them from a static method.

Comment: In one of the four forms the player can customize his own squads with limited resources. 15 is the max number of squads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (ply1Squads.Length == 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        ply1Squads[i] = new Squad();
    }
}
```

You've already declared `ply1Squads` to have 15 `Squad` objects, so it's just a matter of initializing the objects at that point.

You can do the same thing for `ply2Squads`.

BTW, you need to declare `ply1Squads` and `ply2Squads` as `static` as well, as static classes can't have instance members:

```
static Squad[] ply1Squads = new Squad[15];
static Squad[] ply2Squads = new Squad[15];
```

By default, these will be private variables, so you'll want properties for these two arrays as well:

```
public static Squad[] Ply1Squads
{
    get
    {
        return ply1Squads;
    }
    set
    {
        ply1Squads = value;
    }
}

public static Squad[] Ply2Squads
{
    get
    {
        return ply2Squads;
    }
    set
    {
        ply2Squads = value;
    }
}
```

**Additional Thoughts**

If your design goal is to have `MedGameController` handle all the information related to the squads, I'd move away from what you *appear* to be doing - creating duplicate methods for each `Squad` array (i.e., `Player1Squads`).  Instead, pass in a flag of some sort telling the controller which array to use, like this:

```
public void CreateSquads(int playerNum)
{

    select (playerNum)
    {
        case 1:
            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            {
                ply1Squads[i] = new Squad();
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            {
                ply2Squads[i] = new Squad();
            }
            break;
        default:
            // Handle wrong number here
            break;
    }
}
```

That's a (very small) refactoring step.  I would come up with a list of things you want the controller to do, and then figure out how to avoid a 1-1 mapping of every function to both arrays.

Hopefully this makes some sense and gives you a direction to go in.  I have some more ideas tickling the back of my brain, but I can't pull them out to the front yet.  If I do, I'll add more if you're interested (what's another edit or two after the first half-dozen, right? :) ).

Comment: Yes that works great, thanks. This isn't what I was looking for because I was trying to check if an instance of the Squad object existed in the array but this is a lot better because I will just add a boolean to the Squad class called isAlive to check if the player has set up that squad. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it helped.  If you're willing, please mark the question as answered.  Happy coding! :)

Comment: @zack misso - the list of things you want the controller to do didn't show up.

Comment: nvm.... It gave me an exception handleing error in the first part but I solved it by just taking out the if (....Length == 0). For some reason it wouldn't create the instances but it works now

Comment: How do you say it's answered. I'm new to this forum and I don't know all of its mechanics yet.

Comment: @zack misso - There should be a check mark under my answer.  Click on that and it should turn green.  Thanks.